# How to change the color of sidebar in bootstrap

Tags: css

by default it is blue color , I wanted it to change in green color. 
Please somebody help me . I am new to this.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3" id="sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav nav-collapse collapse">
                    <li> <a href="dashboard_admin.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="add_employee.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Add Employee</a> </li>
                    <li class="active"> <a href="view_edit_delete_emp.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> View Edit Delete Employee</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="add_users.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Add User</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="view_user.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> View User</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="edit_delete_users.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> View Edit Delete User</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> View Leave Request</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Leave History</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-success pull-right">731</span> Employees</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-success pull-right">812</span> Users</a></li>
                    <li>  <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-info pull-right">27</span> Today's Leaves</a></li>
                    <li>  <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-info pull-right">1,234</span> Leave Requests</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Did you add Css code ? like color: blue;

Comment: Thanks for helping me dhaval & dev. I have put my code please check with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change** the background-color property of the sidebar. But first select the element on the webpage by inspecting it. **Right click** on the page element and select **Inspect Element** and check for the appropriate property.